# boost::filesystem::path gives only first char

Tags: c++, windows, boost

I store path to some executable in boost::filesystem::path.
When I try to use it with standard boost functions like create_directory I see that nothing works.
When I print the value stored in boost::filesystem::path I get only the first char.

```cpp
const std::string path("c:\\test\\file");
boost::filesystem::path p(path);
printf("%s\n", p.c_str());
```

I expect to see "c:\test\file" in console but get only "c".

On Linux this code works perfectly as expected. On Windows I have behaviour as I described. What is the root of a problem?

ps. boost library version is 1.70

Comment: Is `p.c_str()` a Unicode string on Windows?

Comment: From [documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#path-Conversions-to-generic-format): "*For Windows-like implementations, including MinGW, `path::value_type` is `wchar_t`.*"

Comment: you are right, wprintf(L"%s\n", p.c_str()); prints correctly

Answer (score 3):

for getting `std::string` **instead** of `std::wstring` crossplatform, u can use `boost::fileystem::path::string()` instead of c_str():

```
const std::string path("c:\\test\\file");
boost::filesystem::path p(path);
std::cout << p.string();
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to **@StPiere**'s answer (I cannot comment it because of not enough reputation), this is not mandatory to use

```
std::cout
```

even with

```
boost::fileystem::path::string()
```

you can just change the code in your question to:

```
const std::string path("c:\\test\\file");
boost::filesystem::path p(path);
printf("%s\n", p.string().c_str());
```